# How to implement Facebook and Twitter into an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter

Hey guys! I'm making my own Facebook app (or Twitter) and I would like to know how to implement it into your iPHone app.
If anyone could help me, send me a link or something
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.getsharekit.com/

ShareKit allows you to add support for many social sites to your app. It's super great and free. Check it out. You can look at the code to see how endlessly complicated the facebook/twitter apis are :)

Comment: +1 for ShareKit if you're open to some 3rd party code. Very slicka and easy. (Can't vouch for the quality of the code, I haven't used it. Could be awesome.)

Comment: I have used it, and so far I like it.

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/213 
You can take a look for Facebook API.