# How to share link from the iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, share

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement Facebook and Twitter into an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312147/how-to-implement-facebook-and-twitter-into-an-iphone-app)

I want to share links from my iPhone app to Facebook or Twitter. How do I do this? Is there any built-in iPhone API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to it.. use ShareKit (http://getsharekit.com/) its easy!

Answer (score 0):

Use facebook-ios-sdk
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk